# Django ORM, Insert None datetime as 0 into MySQL

Tags: python, mysql, django

I have a MySQL database that is used by another application besides Django. That application uses `'0000-00-00 00:00:00'` as default value for datetimes.

Django (v1.5.5) interprets `'0000-00-00 00:00:00'` datetime as `None` when reading the database and `None` as `NULL` when writing into the database. This causes an error since the database defines the field as `NOT NULL`.

Manually setting:

```
model.datetime = '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
```

Doesn't work because Django feels that this is an invalid date.

How do I create a custom datetime field which inserts `None` as `'0000-00-00 00:00:00'`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a custom `DateTimeField` and override the `get_db_prep_value`. The method is copypasted from the django source and a case is added for handling `None`. The value should be converted in a database specific manner so this is a bit hacky but it works as long as the database accepts `0000-00-00 00:00:00` as a datetime.

```
from django.db import models

class ZeroDateTimeField(models.DateTimeField):
    def get_db_prep_value(self, value, connection, prepared=False):
        # Casts datetimes into the format expected by the backend
        if not prepared:
            value = self.get_prep_value(value)

        # Use zeroed datetime instead of NULL
        if value is None:
            return  "0000-00-00 00:00:00"

        else:
            return connection.ops.value_to_db_datetime(value)
```

EDIT: This answer was written for Django 1.5 and support with other versions has not been tested.

Comment: do you have a sample of the python code where you use this method? What kind of object is the connection parameter?

Comment: @JonathanVance I never directly use this method but it overrides default behavior of Django. `connection.ops.value_to_db_datetime(None)` would return `'null'` but I wanted `'0000-00-00 00:00:00'`. I use this class as a field on a model just like `models.DateTimeField` is normally used.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Seppo, this answer really helped! See my answer for a variant of this that works in django 1.9 and might be more future-proof.

Answer (score 3):

building on Seppo's solution (which didn't work for django 1.9.4 because of lacking connection.ops.value_to_db_datetime), I ended up using a custom DateTimeField as follows:

```
from django.db import models

class ZeroDateTimeField(models.DateTimeField):
    def get_db_prep_value(self, value, connection, prepared=False):
        value = super( ZeroDateTimeField, self ).get_db_prep_value( value, connection, prepared )
        if value is None:
            return  "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
        return value
```

Then just use ZeroDateTimeField in your models instead of DateTimeField.

works like a charm and I got around having to tell the customer to fix his mysql db ;-)

EDIT: I ended up overriding constructor to set null=True and blank=True to ease use of automatically generated models. Since this may be useful for some, here it is (this is optional and questionable):

```
def __init__(self, verbose_name=None, name=None, auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False, **kwargs):
    kwargs['null'] = True
    kwargs['blank'] = True
    super( ZeroDateTimeField, self ).__init__(verbose_name, name, auto_now, auto_now_add, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 0):

What happens when you add [`default` parameter to the datetime field](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#default)?

`my_date = fields.DateTimeField(default=0)`

I think if MySQL is accepting it, Django should too.

Comment: `default` didn't affect the behaviour.