# Unable to set default vale of DateTimeField to "0000-00-00 00:00:00"

Tags: python, django, database, django-models

```
fld_date_time = models.DateTimeField(db_column='FLD_DATE_TIME', blank=True, null=True, default="0001-00-00 00:00:00")
```

This field in models.py throws error as:

["'0000-00-00 00:00:00' value has the correct format (YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM[:ss[.uuuuuu]][TZ]) but it is an invalid date/time."]

How to add the default value in django?

Comment: Well like it says, that's an invalid date/time. So you can't set it as the default. Because it isn't valid.

Comment: Well that is correct, there is no 0th day, nor a 0th month.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well the problem is that your default value makes no sense. There is no zero-th day, nor is there a zero-th month. The smallest date Python can represent as a `datetime` object is:

```
>>> datetime.min
datetime.datetime(1, 1, 1, 0, 0)
```

so January 1st, 1. In some (most) databases, the range is even more restrictive. For example in [MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/datetime.html) the range is:

> The `DATE` type is used for values with a date part but no time part.
>   MySQL retrieves and displays `DATE` values in `'YYYY-MM-DD'` format.
>   The **supported range is `'1000-01-01'` to `'9999-12-31'`**.
>
> The `DATETIME` type is used for values that contain both date and time
>   parts. MySQL retrieves and displays `DATETIME` values in `'YYYY-MM-DD
>   HH:MM:SS'` format. **The supported range is `'1000-01-01 00:00:00'` to
>   `'9999-12-31 23:59:59'`**.
>
> The `TIMESTAMP` data type is used for values that contain both date
>   and time parts. **`TIMESTAMP` has a range of `'1970-01-01 00:00:01'` UTC
>   to `'2038-01-19 03:14:07'` UTC**.

It is true that MySQL has a "zero date":

> Invalid `DATE`, `DATETIME`, or `TIMESTAMP` values are converted to the
>   "zero" value of the appropriate type (`'0000-00-00'` or `'0000-00-00
>   00:00:00'`).

But there is no good way to wrap this to the `datetime` object, since as said before, it is out of the representable range.

You can use a solution proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21382250/67579) that basically constructs a new Django `ZeroDateTimeField` to map `None` on this zero value. But you can, to the best of my knowledge, not do this with a standard `DateTimeField`.

You thus either can use the minimum representable `datetime` object representable by your database, or use `NULL` instead.